# Load Multiple Property file in Spring app by folder not working in Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to load a set of properties using the Spring PropertyPlaceHolder works properly on both Tomcat and Weblogic. Now I changed it to load all property files in folder , and it is working good in Tomcat and not working on Weblogic.

Can you please help where I went wrong.

Here is the code snippet I changed in XML

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${environment.config}*.properties
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

With Weblogic, it could not able to find Keys, so application is not loading up.

```
Using 
      Spring 4.1.5
      Tomcat 8
      Weblogic : 10.3.6
```

I also try to add the           org.springframework.beans.factory.config.*
in weblogic.xml, but no help.

Comment: The property files are on the classpath or outside?

Comment: outside, basically maintaining somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I customized the load of property files by using *.properties in applicationcontext.xml. I extended  "PropertiesFactoryBean" and initialized the class and read all the properties from the folders as below

```
public static List<Properties>  loadAllProperties() {
        File[] files = new File(System.getProperty("environment.config")).listFiles();
        List<Properties>  lstOfProperties = new ArrayList<>();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    String filename = file.getName();
                    String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, filename.length());

                    if (("properties").equals(extension)) {
                        Properties props = new Properties();
                        try {
                            props.load(new FileReader(file));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            LOGGER.error("Loading Properties " , e);
                        }
                         lstOfProperties.add(props);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return lstOfProperties;
    }
```

Then using the two methods "setPropertiesArray" and "mergeProperties" of the PropertiesFactoryBean, I have added all required properties to the system on load.

There might be better option as well but this worked for me, may be helpful for others.